# qmake 4.8.4 has broken custom targets due to capitalisation. How do I work around it?

Tags: qmake

My .pro file has extra stuff in it:

```
win32 {
    OUT_PWD_SHELL = $$replace(OUT_PWD, /, \\)

    autoversion.target = $$OUT_PWD\\autoversioninfo.h
    autoversion.depends = FORCE
    autoversion.commands = $$PWD/../../AutoBuildVersion.exe $$replace(PWD, /, \\) $$OUT_PWD_SHELL
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += autoversion
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD\\autoversioninfo.h
}
```

This fails to work as expected because in the generated makefile `DESTDIR_TARGET` has a new dependency added that starts `d:\` but the rule generated for autoversion starts with `D:/`. I can improve this slightly by replacing all `/` with `\`, but the case sensitivity still breaks it and the target is not built.

If I remove the full path from `autoversion.target` and `PRE_TARGETDEPS` then it solves that problem, but then when calculating dependencies, the rule for the `cpp` file that includes the generated header changes to give an explicit path to the header in the dependencies, and that path points to the source directory and not the output directory where the generated file is produced. This causes make to barf and not produce the generated file.

I don't know why qmake changes the case handling of the drive, it is very irritating, but how do I get this all to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good solution. The best I came up with is to use a phony target that always runs to generate the header file. On the downside this slows the build when the header file already exists, but on the upside, it allows the build to complete.

```
win32 {
    OUT_PWD_SHELL = $$replace(OUT_PWD, /, \\)

    gen_autoversion.target = GENERATE_AUTOVERSIONINFO
    gen_autoversion.commands = $$PWD/../../AutoBuildVersion.exe $$replace(PWD, /, \\) $$OUT_PWD_SHELL

    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += gen_autoversion

    PRE_TARGETDEPS += GENERATE_AUTOVERSIONINFO
}
```

I am not sure that PRE_TARGETDEPS is actually needed here.